# How to use PySpark to analysis below events?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Assume we have a DataFrame(df) below in PySpark. And, how to use PySpark to get the duration (in mins) between each biking event and the driving event? And, assume for each biking will have only one corresponding driving event; However, within a day there could be multiple "biking - driving" pairs.  Eventually, store the final results into data frame, including biking__time, biking_event, driving_time, driving_event, and each_durations, etc)

Notes: there can be other events between biking and driving, such as a person can start from biking, running, swimming then driving.

One example refers to below table:

The duration of date 03/01/2018 between biking and driving is: 8:12 - 5:12 = 3 hours = 180 mins

|  | TimeDetails | Event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/1/2018 5:12 | Biking |
| 2 | 3/1/2018 6:12 | Swimming |
| 3 | 3/1/2018 7:12 | Hiking |
| 4 | 3/1/2018 8:12 | Driving |
| 5 | 3/2/2018 9:12 | Biking |
| 6 | 3/2/2018 10:12 | Swimming |
| 7 | 3/2/2018 11:12 | Swimming |
| 8 | 3/2/2018 12:12 | Driving |
| 9 | 3/2/2018 13:12 | Swimming |

Below is the sample output:

|  | biking_time | event_name1 | driving_time | event_name2 | durations_inMins |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/1/2018 5:12 | biking | 3/1/2018 8:12 | driving | 180 |
| 2 | 3/2/2018 9:12 | biking | 3/2/2018 12:12 | driving | 180 |

Below is some of my code:

```
biking_df = df.filter(df.Event == 'Biking)
driving_df = df.filter(df.Event == 'Driving')
```

Can someone please provide me with some code in PySpark?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exemple (I added another day with a missing Driving record - the solution will now also handle that):

```
df  = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
('1','3/1/2018 5:12','Biking')
,('2','3/1/2018 6:12','Swimming')
,('3','3/1/2018 7:12','Hiking')
,('4','3/1/2018 8:12','Driving')
,('5','3/2/2018 9:12','Biking')
,('6','3/2/2018 10:12','Swimming')
,('7','3/2/2018 11:12','Swimming')
,('8','3/2/2018 12:12','Driving')
,('9','3/2/2018 13:12','Swimming')
,('10','3/3/2018 9:10','Biking')
,('11','3/3/2018 9:50','Swimming')
,('12','3/3/2018 10:30','Swimming')
,('13','3/3/2018 11:12','Hiking')
  ], ['index','TimeDetails','Event']
)
```

Solution

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df\
.withColumn('TimeDetails', F.to_timestamp('TimeDetails', 'M/d/y H:m'))\
.withColumn('date', F.to_date('TimeDetails'))

#Finding all possible dates in the original dataset:
date_interval = df\
                .agg(
                    F.date_trunc("dd", F.max(F.col("date"))).alias("max_date"),
                    F.date_trunc("dd", F.min(F.col("date"))).alias("min_date"))\
                .withColumn('date_interval', F.explode(F.expr('sequence(min_date, max_date, interval 1 day)')))\
                .select('date_interval')\
                .withColumn('date_interval', F.to_date('date_interval'))

#Imputing those dates on biking and drivig subsets

biking_df = date_interval\
                .join(df.filter(df.Event == 'Biking'),date_interval.date_interval == df.date,'left')\
                .withColumn('Event', F.coalesce(F.col('Event'), F.lit('Biking')))\
                .select('date_interval',F.col('TimeDetails').alias('biking_time'),F.col('Event').alias('event_name1'))

driving_df = date_interval\
                .join(df.filter(df.Event == 'Driving'),date_interval.date_interval == df.date,'left')\
                .withColumn('Event', F.coalesce(F.col('Event'), F.lit('Driving')))\
                .select('date_interval',F.col('TimeDetails').alias('driving_time'),F.col('Event').alias('event_name2'))

result = biking_df\
    .join(driving_df, 'date_interval')\
    .withColumn('durations_inMins',(F.unix_timestamp("driving_time") - F.unix_timestamp('biking_time'))/60)\
    .select('biking_time','event_name1','driving_time','event_name2','durations_inMins')


result.show()
```

The output:

```
+-------------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+----------------+
|        biking_time|event_name1|       driving_time|event_name2|durations_inMins|
+-------------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+----------------+
|2018-03-01 05:12:00|     Biking|2018-03-01 08:12:00|    Driving|           180.0|
|2018-03-02 09:12:00|     Biking|2018-03-02 12:12:00|    Driving|           180.0|
|2018-03-03 09:10:00|     Biking|               null|    Driving|            null|
+-------------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------+----------------+
```

Comment: thank you! On the other hand, "if Biking is started and not finished by Driving. If that's the case, the window function used would need to handle an imputation." how can we implement in this case. Thank you again.

Comment: Then, if the corresponding driving is not present, what would define the duration? what would be the rule is biking starts and it's not finished by driving?

Comment: we might just need to ignore in this case, if there is no matching driving event. So there will not be a duration. or can we just list out the biking started but there is no corresponding driving event.

Comment: OK, and what would be the boundary for each calculation? The same day? So the possibilities are: biking is started on day D. Calculation is done when one of the conditions happen: driving is found in day D or Day D ends and there is no event 'driving'. Is that correct?

Comment: yes they should happen within the same day

Comment: I updated with another approach also covering that

Comment: nice! thank you so much. Meanwhile, if you could take a look at my other two questions related to the problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71261876/how-to-use-pyspark-to-dealing-with-below-data and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71263972/how-to-use-pyspark-to-handle-get-below-durations     really appreciated!

Comment: ok! Please mark as an answer and upvote!

Comment: thank you I am looking into your solutions and will upvote for sure!!!! thank you again.!!!!!!!