# How to use PySpark to dealing with below data?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's assume we have a DataFrame(df) defined below in PySpark. And, how to use PySpark to get the duration between biking action immediately after running action. And save the results into a datefrmaework including running_timedeatails, running, biking_timedeatails, biking, durations, etc.

below two durations will qualify for the date 3/1/18, since both actions are within the same date, and the biking action immediately happens after running action. (Assume only two actions)

10:12 (biking time) - 9:12 (running time) = 1 hour

13:12 (biking time) - 12:12 (runing time) = 1 hour

Sample df below:

| timedeatils | actions |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3/1/18 5:12 | Biking |  |
| 3/1/18 6:12 | Running |  |
| 3/1/18 7:12 | Running |  |
| 3/1/18 8:12 | Running |  |
| 3/1/18 9:12 | Running |  |
| 3/1/18 10:12 | Biking |  |
| 3/1/18 11:12 | Biking |  |
| 3/1/18 12:12 | Running |  |
| 3/1/18 13:12 | Biking |  |
| 3/2/18 4:12 | Biking |  |
| 3/2/18 5:12 | Biking |  |
| 3/2/18 6:12 | Running |  |
| 3/2/18 7:12 | Biking |  |
| 3/2/18 8:12 | Running |  |
| 3/3/18 4:16 | Biking |  |
| 3/4/18 5:13 | Running |  |
| 3/4/18 6:13 | Running |  |
| 3/4/18 7:13 | Running |  |
| 3/4/18 8:13 | Running |  |
| 3/4/18 9:13 | Running |  |
| 3/4/18 10:13 | Running |  |
| 3/4/18 11:13 | Biking |  |

Some of my code below:

```
 df  = spark.createDataFrame(
      [
    (3/1/2018 5:12','Biking')
    ,(3/1/2018 6:12',Running)
    ,(3/1/2018 7:12',Running)
    ,(3/1/2018 8:12',Running)
    ,(3/1/2018 9:12',Running)
    ,(3/1/2018 10:12','Biking')
    ,(3/1/2018 11:12','Biking')
    ,(3/1/2018 12:12',Running)
    ,(3/1/2018 13:12','Biking')
    ,(3/2/2018 4:12','Biking')
    ,(3/2/2018 5:12','Biking')
    ,(3/2/2018 6:12',Running)
    ,(3/2/2018 7:12','Biking')
    ,(3/2/2018 8:12',Running)
    ,(3/3/2018 4:16','Biking')
    ,(3/4/2018 5:13','Biking')
    ,(3/4/2018 6:13',Running)
    ,(3/4/2018 7:13',Running)
    ,(3/4/2018 8:13',Running)
    ,(3/4/2018 9:13',Running)
    ,(3/4/2018 10:13',Running)
    ,(3/4/2018 11:12',Biking)
      ], ['TimeDetails','Actions']
    )
```

We only care about the duration between " the first Biking action after the running action". Basically, duration = Biking_timestamp - running_timestamp (only consider the biking happen after running event, and biking should be to the first biking action after the running event)

Notes:

1. both events should be within the same day
2. like a date " 3/3/18 4:16 "Biking" we will not compare to the previous date "running"; therefore for 3/3/18 4:16, there will be no such duration

Sample output:

|  | Biking_time | action_1 | Running_time | action_2 | Durations_in_Hour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3/1/18 10:12 | Biking | 3/1/18 9:12 | Running | 1 |
| 2 | 3/1/18 13:12 | Biking | 3/1/18 13:12 | Running | 1 |
| 3 | 3/2/18 7:12 | Biking | 3/2/18 6:12 | Running | 1 |
| 4 | 3/4/18 11:13 | Biking | 3/4/18 10:13 | Running | 1 |

Can someone please provide me with some code in PySpark? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data:

```
 df  = spark.createDataFrame(
      [
    ('3/1/2018 5:12','Biking')
    ,('3/1/2018 6:12','Running')
    ,('3/1/2018 7:12','Running')
    ,('3/1/2018 8:12','Running')
    ,('3/1/2018 9:12','Running')
    ,('3/1/2018 10:12','Biking')
    ,('3/1/2018 11:12','Biking')
    ,('3/1/2018 12:12','Running')
    ,('3/1/2018 13:12','Biking')
    ,('3/2/2018 4:12','Biking')
    ,('3/2/2018 5:12','Biking')
    ,('3/2/2018 6:12','Running')
    ,('3/2/2018 7:12','Biking')
    ,('3/2/2018 8:12','Running')
    ,('3/3/2018 4:16','Biking')
    ,('3/4/2018 5:13','Biking')
    ,('3/4/2018 6:13','Running')
    ,('3/4/2018 7:13','Running')
    ,('3/4/2018 8:13','Running')
    ,('3/4/2018 9:13','Running')
    ,('3/4/2018 10:13','Running')
    ,('3/4/2018 11:12','Biking')
      ], ['TimeDetails','Actions']
    ).withColumn('TimeDetails', F.to_timestamp('TimeDetails', 'M/d/y H:m'))
```

Solution using Window functions:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T
from pyspark.sql import Window as W


w = W.partitionBy('date').orderBy(F.asc("TimeDetails"))

df = df\
    .withColumn('date', F.to_date('TimeDetails'))\
    .withColumn("Prev_Action", F.lag(F.col('Actions')).over(w))\
    .withColumn("Prev_Action_ts", F.lag(F.col('TimeDetails')).over(w))\
    .withColumn('Bike_after_Run?', F.when((col('Actions')=='Biking') & (col('Prev_Action')=='Running'),1).otherwise(0))\
    .withColumn('Durations_in_Hours',(F.unix_timestamp("TimeDetails") - F.unix_timestamp('Prev_Action_ts'))/3600)\
    .withColumn('Durations_in_Hours', F.round(F.col('Durations_in_Hours'),0).cast(T.IntegerType()))\
    .filter(col('Bike_after_Run?') == 1)\
    .select(F.col('TimeDetails').alias('Biking_time'),
            F.col('Actions').alias('action_1'),
            F.col('Prev_Action_ts').alias('Running_time'),
            F.col('Prev_Action').alias('action_2'),
            'Durations_in_Hours')\
    .orderBy('TimeDetails')

df.show()
```

```
+-------------------+--------+-------------------+--------+------------------+
|Biking_time        |action_1|Running_time       |action_2|Durations_in_Hours|
+-------------------+--------+-------------------+--------+------------------+
|2018-03-01 10:12:00|Biking  |2018-03-01 09:12:00|Running |1                 |
|2018-03-01 13:12:00|Biking  |2018-03-01 12:12:00|Running |1                 |
|2018-03-02 07:12:00|Biking  |2018-03-02 06:12:00|Running |1                 |
|2018-03-04 11:12:00|Biking  |2018-03-04 10:13:00|Running |1                 |
+-------------------+--------+-------------------+--------+------------------+
```